# Typing array with different head and rest types

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to properly type an array which looks like this:

```
type HeadElem = { type: "Head" }
type RestElem = { type: "Rest" }

const arr = [{ type: "Head" }, { type: "Rest" }, { type: "Rest" }]
```

Number of the rest elements is not limited, but the first element is always a head element. Somewhat working is to type the array like in example below, but then the `...rest` has incorrect type of `(HeadElem | RestElem)[]`.

```
type Arr = [HeadElem] & RestElem[];
const [head, ...rest] = arr as Arr;
```

What is the correct type for `Arr` so the `...rest` is deduced to be just `RestElem[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
type Arr = [HeadElem, ...RestElem[]]
```

Comment: Ah I have never seen spread operator used in type annotation. Good to know this is an option.